# Finding SAP table relations?

Tags: sap-data-dictionary

I'm new to SAP. I have access to the SAP database, but not to the SAP GUI.
I wanna know the tables relation i.e., how to join two tables.

Suppose, if I want to know all the relations `VNVK` has, where should I start? I can only view the primary keys and not the foreign keys for all the tables. I read some posts from this forum and got this information:

- `DD02L`: SAP Tables
- `DD05S`: Foreign key fields
- `DD09L`: DD: Technical settings of tables
- `DD26S`: Base tables and foreign key relationships

but the `DD26S` table doesn't give me these information either.

I even tried to get the table and column description and then try to join, but it's a tedious process.

I got a document with SAP table relations but it doesn't have all the modules in it.

Any holistic documentation about all of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone wants you to do the job, they have to give you the proper tools. You need frontend access (at least read-only) to do this. So take a pointed stick and poke whoever is responsible until you get the necessary permissions.

That being said, you should check out the [IDES installation provided by consolut](http://www.consolut.net/en/s/sap-ides-access/discover-sap-ides.html) - they offer free (read only) access, and that might be enough for you. Read [this](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/cf/21ea0b446011d189700000e8322d00/frameset.htm) for information about the dictionary structures and [this](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_46c/helpdata/en/ea/e9a3bb4c7211d189520000e829fbbd/frameset.htm) for information on the tools.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.but i have all the sap table in SQL server. I want to find relations between tables for some modules only.

Comment: Don't go there. Accessing the tables without the SAP system in between is a really really bad idea. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658910/how-to-import-data-to-sap/2661732#2661732 and especially http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115170/how-to-decode-sap-text-from-from-stxl-clustd/2116137#2116137 for some of the reasons.

Answer (score 2):

On STechno you can find a list of SAP tables: http://www.stechno.net/sap-tables.html

where table relations for any SAP table can be seen by via field references. Another way this resource provides is graphical visualization of the table relations. For example, MARA connections look [like this](http://www.stechno.net/sap-tables.html?view=graph&id=MARA)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm from consolut, you can also program Abap but not in our IDES. 
For programming try our Mini-SAP system.

Answer (score 0):

There are are several vendors out there that offer SAP systems for short or long term use as sandboxes, one of them is also Bettisworth associates. Simply google them