# Repository / tool for determining table relationships (or possible relationships)

Tags: abap, sap-erp, sap-data-dictionary

Is there a repository/tool (within or outside SAP ERP) that can help me determine the fields that I can use when trying to link 2 tables (or possibly show other necessary tables before I can link the 2 tables) between SAP ERP tables?

I've been thinking of creating my own custom tool in our DEV system but just in case there's already one, please let me know. Again, thank you in advance! :)

Started creating my own report. As of now, all I do is compare tables.

Comment: SAP is a company. Which SAP software are you talking about?

Comment: @SandraRossi My apologies, SAP ERP.

Comment: Not a unique one. An experienced developer uses many ways to do that: CDS Views, foreign keys in the ABAP Dictionary (including the Graphic View), value tables, SQL trace, ABAP debug, SD11 Data Modeler (obsolete/rare usage), and SAP forums of course.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding SAP table relations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335733/finding-sap-table-relations)